# Не могу добавить еще 1 таблицу для вывода SQL php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$db_host="";  
$db_user="";    
$db_password="";    
$db_name = "";  
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Ошибка соединения: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit;  }
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
if ($stmt = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM vtiger_contactdetails, vtiger_timesheet, vtiger_timesheetcf WHERE vtiger_contactdetails.contactid = vtiger_timesheet.cf_2295 AND vtiger_timesheet.cf_2295 = vtiger_timesheet.timesheetid')) {

while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['lastname'].' '.$row['cf_2295'].'<br />';
 }
 }

?>
```

Код работает без vtiger_timesheet, и последнего условия 
 
AND vtiger_timesheet.cf_2295 = vtiger_timesheet.timesheetid

Нужно что бы все таблицы подключить и что бы условия работали. 
Подскажите как правильно написать запросы?

Comment: Во первых выполните полный запрос в mysql напрямую.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать `JOIN`.

Вот неплохая статья о объединениях таблиц [Объяснение SQL объединений JOIN](http://www.skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Obyasnenie_SQL_obedinenii_JOIN_INNER_OUTER.html)

```
SELECT * FROM vtiger_contactdetails 
JOIN vtiger_timesheet
ON vtiger_contactdetails.contactid = vtiger_timesheet.cf_2295 
JOIN vtiger_timesheetcf
ON  vtiger_timesheet.cf_2295 = vtiger_timesheet.timesheetid
```

как-то так, возможно `ORDER BY`  в конце еще нужно использовать..нужно тестить

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас гляну, спасибо

Comment: vtiger_timesheet другая таблица? эсли да то ща напишу выборку в сообщении

Comment: Да, это другая таблица.
В этом коде задействованны 3 таблицы
vtiger_timesheet 
vtiger_contactdetails
vtiger_timesheetcf

Comment: Супер, все работает, спасибо